# Best way to remove the object from an array using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array of objects. I want to remove multiple objects from that array.

I have used below code which is working absolutely fine, but I need to check with you guys if there is better way to do that or its fine.

I have done it with angularjs and js.

`Orders` is the main array on which operations are performed.
`Order` is array of selected items to remove from main array `Orders`

```
$scope.Order = {};
$scope.removeOrders = function () {
        angular.forEach($scope.Order, function (data) {
            for (var i = $scope.Orders.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if ($scope.Orders[i].Name == data.Name) {
                    $scope.Orders.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it quite a bit shorter using `filter`:

```
$scope.removeOrders = function () {
    $scope.Orders = $scope.Orders.filter(function(order){
        return !$scope.Order.some(function(remove){
            return remove.Name === order.Name;
        });
    }); // remove the order from $scope.Orders, if it's name is found in $scope.Order
};
```

Comment: I don't like this approach. array.filter() creates a new array with a new reference, which will confuse AngularJs, and you will have issues with the update of the view. Also, if this object is referenced else where, the other object won't be updated.

Comment: Filter inside `foreach` using some different conditions as OP mentioned ?

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe: That is simply not true. Angular can handle `filter` just fine, I use it all the time -.-

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe, what exactly would "confuse" Angular?

Comment: `order` is an item in `$scope.Orders`. the OP is comparing `$scope.Orders[i].Name`. So no, @Satpal. it shouldn't be `indexOf(order)`. That said, like this can't work, either. editing my code.

Comment: @Cerbrus : It will be very appreciable if you can elaborate about ``some`` function that you used in ``$scope.Order.some``. what it does ?

Comment: Ah, of course!  _"The [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function."_ This means that if ___any___ of the elements in the array, when passed to the function in `some` makes that function return `true`, the `some` function will return `true`. Otherwise, it will return `false`.

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe: how about [a _completely_ different approach](http://jsfiddle.net/c9h4rpeu/4/) using `$scope`? That works just as you'd expect.

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe: Oh, and your fiddle was resetting the wrong property. [When fixed, that also works as expected.](http://jsfiddle.net/drg5v5uv/1/)